# Programmatically rename data frame columns using lookup data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

What is the best way to batch rename columns using a lookup data frame?

Can I do it as part of a pipe?

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data_frame(
  a = seq(1, 10)
  , b = seq(10, 1)
  , c = rep(1, 10)
)

df_lookup <- data_frame(
  old_name = c("b", "c", "a")
  , new_name = c("y", "z", "x")
)
```

I know how to do it manually

```
df %>% 
  rename(x = a
    , y = b
    , z = c)
```

I am seeking a solution in `tidyverse` / `dplyr` packages.

Comment: `names(df)[match(old_name,names(df))] <- new_name` I am pretty this question has been answered before. I remember upvoting it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `rlang`; Firstly build up a list of names using `syms`, and then splice the arguments to `rename` with `UQS` or `!!!` operator:

```
library(rlang); library(dplyr)

df %>% rename(!!!syms(with(df_lookup, setNames(old_name, new_name))))

# A tibble: 10 x 3
#       x     y     z
#   <int> <int> <dbl>
# 1     1    10     1
# 2     2     9     1
# 3     3     8     1
# 4     4     7     1
# 5     5     6     1
# 6     6     5     1
# 7     7     4     1
# 8     8     3     1
# 9     9     2     1
#10    10     1     1
```

Answer (score 2):

You could write your own helper to make it easier

```
rename_to <- function(data, old, new) {
  data %>% rename_at(old, function(x) new[old==x])
}

df %>% rename_to(df_lookup$old_name, df_lookup$new_name)
```

Answer (score 2):

In base-R:

```
names(df)[match(df_lookup$old_name,names(df))] <- df_lookup$new_name

# # A tibble: 10 x 3 
#        x     y     z 
#    <int> <int> <dbl> 
#  1     1    10     1 
#  2     2     9     1 
#  3     3     8     1 
#  4     4     7     1 
#  5     5     6     1 
#  6     6     5     1 
#  7     7     4     1 
#  8     8     3     1 
#  9     9     2     1 
# 10    10     1     1
```

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setnames(setDT(df), old = df_lookup$old_name, new = df_lookup$new_name)

#      x  y z 
#  1:  1 10 1 
#  2:  2  9 1 
#  3:  3  8 1 
#  4:  4  7 1 
#  5:  5  6 1 
#  6:  6  5 1 
#  7:  7  4 1 
#  8:  8  3 1 
#  9:  9  2 1 
# 10: 10  1 1
```